# Multiple Comparisons in R

Tags: r

I need to run a multiple comparison in R. Essentially I have something like this:

| Exposure A | Exposure B | Exposure C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | aaa | aaa |
| bbb | bbb | fff |
| ccc | ccc |  |
| ddd | ddd |  |
| eee | fff |  |
|  | ggg |  |
|  | hhh |  |

I need code that will pop out which exposures each value came from (i.e. ddd shows up in Exposure A and B, ggg shows up in Exposure B, etc.). Maybe something like this:

| Value | Column |
| --- | --- |
| ddd | Exposure A, Exposure B |
| ggg | Exposure B |

I've been able to get how many times a value shows up across the table but am at a loss as to how to get which column (exposure) the values are from.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df <- read_table("Exposure_A    Exposure_B  Exposure_C
aaa aaa aaa
bbb bbb fff") 

df %>%  
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
  summarise(column = str_c(unique(name), collapse = ", "), .by = value)

# A tibble: 3 × 2
  value column                            
  <chr> <chr>                             
1 aaa   Exposure_A, Exposure_B, Exposure_C
2 bbb   Exposure_A, Exposure_B            
3 fff   Exposure_C
```

Comment: Fantastic that worked! Follow up questions 1) can I get it to leave out the nulls or blank spaces from the tibble and 2) how can I get that as a dataframe?

Comment: Can you update your question with a sample of your data? `dput(head(df, 15))`